# Can’t clone repo from GitLab CI in Docker

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm have some trouble with GitLab CI. For the context, it is my first CI that I'm trying to configure.
GitLab is installed via an Omnibus package and is in 9.0.6CE version on a CentOS 6 64bits. GitLab runners are installed on 2 systems: an Ubuntu 16.04 64bits and CentOS 6 64bits. The second runner is on the same server as GitLab. The runners are in version 9.1.1. There are installed through repositories. I have tried with a runner in a Docker service but it doesn't change the result.
The servers are behind a proxy with authentication that limits their access to Internet. I have configured the server to manage the proxy (environment variables and so on) and Docker can retrieve images from Internet.

I have PHP project where I would like to do some PHPUnit test at each push. When I run the runner locally, everything goes fine. But when the runner is activated by GitLab CI then, the git repository can't be cloned. Do you have any solution or even suggestion to resolve the problem?

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: php:7.1.0

before_script:
  - bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null

test:php7.1:
  script:
    - phpunit --coverage-text -c app/
  tags:
    - docker
```

Job result:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.1.1 (6104325)
on arthur-docker (7b16a671)
Using Docker executor with image php:7.1.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:bca6e849844c9924fda99a3d8e271d37d9ed4fb5bc5727c3fe6c3ba171a4fdae for predefined container...
Pulling docker image php:7.1.0 ...
Using docker image php:7.1.0 ID=sha256:97c69bd40b40e1a1338409408ceb61b779097cc857037305450ad9a1ea249695 for build container...
Running on runner-7b16a671-project-138-concurrent-0 via f24c7be7d1da...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/ems/gest_dev'...
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@internal.server.ratp:82/ems/gest_dev.git/' not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Go through the issues here :

1. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1721
2. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22501

Short Answer :

> remote: Git access over HTTP is not allowed

Comment: I have read the issues and none of them resolved my problem. Plus, I don't have a problem with authentication but with the repository being not found.

Answer (score 0):

#### First diagnostic step

Does your `.gitlab-ci.yml` look like this EXACTLY?

```
image: php:7.1.0

before_script:
  - bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null

test:php7.1:
  script:
    - phpunit --coverage-text -c app/
  tags:
  - docker
```

Please note the indentation particularly about `tags:` because your POST shows it YAML correct but Gitlab incorrect. The [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags) say that it needs to be inside a `job` like your `test:php7.1:` job.

Comment: Both protocols are enabled since the beginning. If the problem would be authentication, the error message would say something about it. Isn't it?

Comment: Protocols: OK. Let's advance. No authentication problem: OK (error hints no authentication problem). Can you provide the complete `.gitlab-ci.yml`? (obscure any sensitive information)

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer earlier. I didn't get the notification. The `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the question is already complete. The script `docker_install.sh` just install the dependencies needed to run PHPUnit

Comment: No problem. Will go thru diagnostic steps one at a time. Please see edited answer and comment so we can advance to step two.

Comment: The CI Yaml document is as described in my post. The `tags` belongs to `test:php7.1`